# Why isn't my single-page website loading after deployment?

Tags: ktor

Serving my single page application works fine when run through IntelliJ. I can pull up the site on my dev computer using http://0.0.0.0:8080.

```
2023-11-17 16:41:04.791 [main] INFO  Application - Autoreload is disabled because the development mode is off.
2023-11-17 16:41:05.288 [main] INFO  Application - Application started in 0.549 seconds.
2023-11-17 16:41:05.490 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO  Application - Responding at http://0.0.0.0:8080
2023-11-17 16:44:12.158 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for []
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:0 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.308 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [css, aos.css]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[css, aos.css]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[css, aos.css]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.309 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-4] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, 2023-JamesHeadshot.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, 2023-JamesHeadshot.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, 2023-JamesHeadshot.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.309 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-3] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [css, bootstrap.min.css]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[css, bootstrap.min.css]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[css, bootstrap.min.css]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.309 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-5] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, deploymentexample.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, deploymentexample.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, deploymentexample.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.309 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [css, main.css]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[css, main.css]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[css, main.css]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.316 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-6] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, auditexample.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, auditexample.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, auditexample.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.320 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, utilityexample.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, utilityexample.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, utilityexample.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.330 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-5] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, projectexample.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, projectexample.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, projectexample.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.397 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-6] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [js, core, bootstrap.min.js]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:3 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[js, core, bootstrap.min.js]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:3 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[js, core, bootstrap.min.js]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.397 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-5] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [js, core, jquery.3.2.1.min.js]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:3 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[js, core, jquery.3.2.1.min.js]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:3 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[js, core, jquery.3.2.1.min.js]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.397 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-3] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [js, aos.js]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[js, aos.js]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[js, aos.js]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.397 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [js, core, popper.min.js]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:3 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[js, core, popper.min.js]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:3 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[js, core, popper.min.js]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.397 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [js, now-ui-kit.js]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[js, now-ui-kit.js]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[js, now-ui-kit.js]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.415 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [scripts, main.js]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[scripts, main.js]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[scripts, main.js]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.419 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-5] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, simpleavailsol.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, simpleavailsol.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, simpleavailsol.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.419 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-3] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, advancedavailsol.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, advancedavailsol.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, advancedavailsol.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.419 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-6] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, otheravailsol.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, otheravailsol.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, otheravailsol.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.420 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, intermediateavailsol.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, intermediateavailsol.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, intermediateavailsol.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.423 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, architecture.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, architecture.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, architecture.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.429 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-5] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, efficiency.png]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, efficiency.png]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, efficiency.png]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.429 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-3] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, automation.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, automation.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, automation.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.430 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-6] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, reference-image-1.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, reference-image-1.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, reference-image-1.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.430 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, documentation.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, documentation.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, documentation.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.431 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, reference-image-2.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, reference-image-2.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, reference-image-2.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.431 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-4] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, reference-image-3.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, reference-image-3.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, reference-image-3.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.500 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-4] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, Uptown_Charlotte_2018_taking_by_DJI_Phantom_4_pro_sized.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, Uptown_Charlotte_2018_taking_by_DJI_Phantom_4_pro_sized.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, Uptown_Charlotte_2018_taking_by_DJI_Phantom_4_pro_sized.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:12.504 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [images, CharlotteMap.jpg]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, CharlotteMap.jpg]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[images, CharlotteMap.jpg]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
2023-11-17 16:44:13.034 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [favicon.ico]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:1 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[favicon.ico]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[favicon.ico]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
```

When I use ./gradlew distTar, transfer the resulting tar ball to my production VM, untar it, cd to the bin folder, and then run the application, it starts fine. I can even telnet from my dev computer to the VM's local IP and port 8080 without issue, confirming I have no network issues. But when I attempt to load the page on my dev computer (http://vmip:8080), I get a super short output on the web server but the page does not load.

```
com.hazaqames.consulting-0.0.1/bin/com.hazaqames.consulting
2023-11-17 16:35:57.218 [main] INFO  Application - Autoreload is disabled because the development mode is off.
2023-11-17 16:35:58.293 [main] INFO  Application - Application started in 1.174 seconds.
2023-11-17 16:35:58.741 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO  Application - Responding at http://192.168.1.13:8080
2023-11-17 16:36:02.629 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for []
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /{...}, segment:0 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[]] @ /{...}
      /{...}/(method:GET), segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /{...}/(method:GET)
Matched routes:
  "" -> "<slash>" -> "{...}" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS; Parameters [static-content-path-parameter=[]] @ /{...}/(method:GET)
```

That's it. I get nothing more than those initial lines when I attempt to load the page.

I can peek at the contents of the app's jar file and confirm that there is the expected static folder with my web files, including but not limited to the index.html file in the root and the css, images, and scripts folders with sub-files. So it appears that all is there, but I have no idea how to get more intel about the symptom or even know what to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered two problems that I had to work through. First, I was using staticFiles instead of staticResources. And second, in the staticFiles path, I was referencing the qualified path on my development computer which was obviously different than the path within the "fatJar" file.

Before:

```
routing {
        staticFiles("/", File("src/main/resources/static")) {
            default("index.html")
            preCompressed(CompressedFileType.GZIP)
        }
    }
```

After:

```
routing {
        staticResources("/","static") {
            default("index.html")
            preCompressed(CompressedFileType.GZIP)
        }
    }
```

After fixing this, I was able to build the "fatJar" and run it with a simple java -jar myfile.jar on both my dev computer and the VM without issue.